# Creating a Static Singleton of my Game class throws a linker error 2001?

Tags: c++, static, singleton, linker-errors

Linker error messages "private: static class Worlds::Game * Worlds::Game::instance"
The following are the code segments that are related to the error.

From Game.h

```
static Worlds::Game* instance;
static Worlds::Game* getInstance();
```

From Game.cpp

```
Worlds::Game* instance = 0;

Worlds::Game* Worlds::Game::getInstance()
{
    if (instance)
    {
        return instance;
    }
    else
    {
        return instance = new Worlds::Game();
    }
}
```

So my question is why am I getting this error as I should have all my bases covered for creating a singleton of my game class?

Edit:

I forgot to add in the Game.cpp I have all my Glut Callbacks which need to call the functions in Game that do something.

```
void onKeyDownCallback(unsigned char key, int mouseX, int mouseY)
void onKeyUpCallback(unsigned char key, int mouseX, int mouseY)
void timerCallback(int value)
void onWindowReshapeCallback(int w,int h)
void onMouseClickedCallback(int button, int state, int mouseX, int mouseY)
void onMouseMovedCallback(int deltaX, int deltaY)
void displayCallback()
```

Comment: Please, see how I've edited your post and learn to use the correct foramtting. There is no point in using <code> tags. Just indent the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static Worlds::Game* instance;` - remove this from header. Because `instance` is marked `static` it is copied per each translation unit. And you get as many instances as translated units. But you initialize it only in one translation unit

Also consider implementing a `singleton` this way:

```
Worlds::Game & Worlds::Game::getInstance()
{ 
    static Game instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `static` keyword has two meanings.

When used inside a class, it means a "static variable" or "static method", that can be called without an instance of the object.

However, when used outside of the class body, at the root space of the code file, the meaning is **changed**. In this case, plain old C meaning is used: the symbol marked with 'static' is being hidden from being linked by other modules.

This means, that if you defined your .h file like that, and are #include'ing that .h file in several .cpp modules, then **no other module** will see the "instance" or "getInstance" implementations.

Remove the "static" from the root code scope and it will be fine.

Comment: Ha, *two* meanings? Why would C++ be *that* simple? It has *three* meanings. (the other is specifying static local variables)

Comment: Static local variables have the same meaning as class static fields. It is just the visibility of the name that differs. Actually, as Andrew pointed out, the meaning is ONE, and it is about memory block reservation in a translation unit.. The perceived difference is based only on the visibility of the identifiers.

Comment: I wouldn't say so because their lifetime is different.

Comment: IIRC, the difference in their lifetime (if there is any at all, I really dont remember it now), is neglible to the "user code" as they are guaranteed to be initialized/destroyed before/after entering/quitting the main(). Either way, if you are trying to rely on order of that specific static initialization order you are just asking for problems..